# I want to block system apps from using wifi network

Tags: wi-fi

When i go to security >>data restrict use>> and i do search for any system app , i can not find it. Is there any solution because the manufacture prevents me from blocking them, like as user apps on android

Comment: Since manufacturers do customize their Android OS including their Settings menu, could you [edit] and mention the device model and Android version?

Comment: Share some information about your device and OS. If possible, what apps you are trying to block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `TrackerControl`? It is an open source app that sets up a VPN server and blocks trackers. Once you install it and enable VPN, Go to `Settings > Advanced options > Manage system apps` and enable the toggle. Then all System apps will show up on the dashboard. Tap the icon of any app to revoke internet access. Tap the name of the app to configure more complicated settings for an individual app.

Github: https://github.com/TrackerControl/tracker-control-android/releases/latest/download/TrackerControl-githubRelease-latest.apk

F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/app/net.kollnig.missioncontrol.fdroid

Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kollnig.missioncontrol.play

Comment: Yes, but i need permanently method (even by root), i tried to stop or remove permissions( com.android.permission.INTERNET ) from Androidmanifest files but i get problems such as disappearing the apps after remove that permission also when i tried remove the permission for settings.apk the rom was unable to reboot again, but recently i am testing all method on virtual machine